# Find a method to determine solvability of the system $x^2 +1 \equiv 0 \pmod {p_i}$ for distinct primes $p_i$.

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Find a method to determine solvability of the system $x^2 +1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p_i}$ for distinct primes $p_i$.

Related problem:[Provide polynomial time algorithm for determining solvability of $x^2 + 1 \equiv 0 $ (mod $p$) for $p$ prime.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3898739/provide-polynomial-time-algorithm-for-determining-solvability-of-x2-1-equiv?noredirect=1#comment8041243_3898739)

Comment: as commented at the related problem, $x^2+1\equiv0\bmod p$ is solvable for primes $p=2$ and $p=4k+1$ but not $p=4k+3$

Comment: @helios321 As shown in the table in the [Law of quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Law_of_quadratic_reciprocity) section of Wikipedia's "Quadratic residue" article, for odd primes $p$, $-1$ is a quadratic residue iff $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, just like J.W. Tanner's comment states.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner If the congruence has a solution for each $p_i$ that doesn't imply that the system has a solution does it?

Comment: @helios321:  are you familiar with the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes but I thought only apply to linear congruence, can we convert to linear congruence then?

Comment: the solution to $x^2+1\equiv0\bmod p_i$ is $x\equiv\pm a_i\bmod p_i$ (linear)

Comment: The system of congruences is solvable if and only if each congruence is solvable because of the chinese remainder theorem., hence the system is solvable if and only if no $p_i$ is of the form $4k+3$. In this case, as mentioned , you can use the chinese remainder theorem to find a solution efficiently.